# Predict binning on Neural networks

Tags: python, neural-network

I have a *dataset* as training input with this shape:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDezS.png]

> **First column:** is a random word.
>
> **Second column:** is the sum of its ASCII characters.
>
> **Third column:** LeftLimit of the current Bin.
>
> **Fourth column:** RightLimit of the current Bin.
>
> **Fifth column:** is a bin that is used as a label for this word.

For example, bin $0$ is a label for every word that its sum of ASCII characters is between $117$ to $140$.

I want to create a `neural network` that after training to predict the label (bin) of every word of a huge file that I give.

> What type of neural network do you propose me to use?

Comment: Do you have to use a neural network? From your description of bin 0, this seems deterministic.

Comment: Yes.It is for my thesis and i must do it with nn.I know there are many better ways to do it.